# Please help me to write JUnit test case for this method

Tags: java, junit

```
public boolean meetsPreconditions(final LineFeature feature) {
        if (getModel().RANGES.FormOfWay.SmallSlipRoad.equals(getToolkit().getDictionaryTools()
            .getAttributeFromFeature(feature, getModel().FEATURES.RoadElement.FormOfWay, DictionaryRangeItem.class)
            .getValue())) {
            final RoadElementsChain roadElementsChain = createRoadElementsChainBuilder();
            roadElementsChain.buildRoadElementsChain(feature);
            if (!roadElementsChain.getLineFeatures().isEmpty() && roadElementsChain.getOtherLineFeaturesAtStart().size() > 1
                && roadElementsChain.getOtherLineFeaturesAtEnd().size() > 1) {
                setChainOfRoads(roadElementsChain);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You can use a `mocking framework` like `Mockito`. In your case, you have to mock `RoadElementsChain`

Comment: thank for suggestion. Can you just write the test case structure for this

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `mocking framework` like `Mockito`. In your case, you have to mock `RoadElementsChain` class and test the call of your method `meetsPreconditions` as something like this :

```
    @Mock
    private RoadElementsChain roadElementsChain;

    @Test
    public void testMeetsPreconditions() {
        when(roadElementsChain.getLineFeatures().isEmpty()).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE);
        // Other whens statements

        assertThat(yourClass.meetsPreconditions(feature)).isTrue();
    }
```

Also refactor your code to be more redeable.

Answer (score 0):

First you should refactor the code to simplify your if conditions.

```java
if (getModel().RANGES.FormOfWay.SmallSlipRoad.equals(getToolkit().getDictionaryTools()
            .getAttributeFromFeature(feature, getModel().FEATURES.RoadElement.FormOfWay, DictionaryRangeItem.class)
            .getValue())) { // true case
```

This if condition is hard to read and understand.

```java
// It should be private
// You want to test it so it is protected.
protected isSmallSlipRoad(final LineFeature feature){
    return getModel().RANGES.FormOfWay.SmallSlipRoad.equals(getToolkit().getDictionaryTools()
            .getAttributeFromFeature(feature, getModel().FEATURES.RoadElement.FormOfWay, DictionaryRangeItem.class)
            .getValue())
}

if(isSmallSlipRoad(feature){// true case
}
return false;
```

Then I would negate the if condition to eliminate the else case (which return false). Note that, you should retrun false if the second if condition is not satisfied.

```java
if(!isSmallSlipRoad(feature)){
 return false;
}
final RoadElementsChain roadElementsChain = createRoadElementsChainBuilder();
roadElementsChain.buildRoadElementsChain(feature);
if (!roadElementsChain.getLineFeatures().isEmpty() && 
     roadElementsChain.getOtherLineFeaturesAtStart().size() > 1 && 
     roadElementsChain.getOtherLineFeaturesAtEnd().size() > 1) {
         setChainOfRoads(roadElementsChain);
         return true;
}
return false;
```

Now you can refactor the 2nd if condition wich is the conjuction (and) of three conditions. You can use the [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#:%7E:text=In%20propositional%20logic%20and%20Boolean,both%20valid%20rules%20of%20inference.&text=The%20rules%20allow%20the%20expression,of%20each%20other%20via%20negation.) to rephrase the condition to three negated disjunction (or operation).

In other words, you retrun false if the getLineFeatures is empty OR the start is less or equal 1 OR the end is less or equal 1.

```java
if(!isSmallSlipRoad(feature)){
 return false;
}
final RoadElementsChain roadElementsChain = createRoadElementsChainBuilder();
roadElementsChain.buildRoadElementsChain(feature);
if (roadElementsChain.getLineFeatures().isEmpty()){ // remove negation !
    return false;
}
if(roadElementsChain.getOtherLineFeaturesAtStart().size() <= 1){ // !(x > 1) == (x <= 1)
    return false;
}
if(roadElementsChain.getOtherLineFeaturesAtEnd().size() <=  1) { // !(x > 1) == (x <= 1)
    return false;
}
setChainOfRoads(roadElementsChain);
return true;
} // end of method
```

Now you can merge these if condition with or operation but I would not do it. If you merge the conditions then it will be more difficult to understand it for other developers. Now the code says that if it is smallSlipRoad then false, or if the line features are empty then it is false, ... otherwise it is true. If you will merge the conditions then it would say if anyo of these conditions is satisfied then it is false otherwise its true. Reading the conditions would be difficult I think.

You can also wrap the conditions into private (or protected) methods to further incraese the readability and facilitate testing and negate the isSmallSlipRoad method so none of your conditions are negated in the if statement. (the ! operator can be missed, => small mistakes big troubles)

```java
protected isNotSmallSlipRoad(final LineFeature feature){
    return !getModel().RANGES.FormOfWay.SmallSlipRoad.equals(getToolkit().getDictionaryTools()
            .getAttributeFromFeature(feature, getModel().FEATURES.RoadElement.FormOfWay, DictionaryRangeItem.class)
            .getValue())
}

protected boolean isLineFeaturesEmpty(RoadElementsChain roadElementsChain){
    return roadElementsChain.getLineFeatures().isEmpty();
}

protected boolean isOtherLineFeaturesStartTooShort(RoadElementsChain roadElementsChain){
  return roadElementsChain.getOtherLineFeaturesAtStart().size() <= 1;
}

protected boolean isOtherLineFeaturesEndTooShort(RoadElementsChain roadElementsChain){
  return roadElementsChain.getOtherLineFeaturesAtEnd().size() <= 1;
}


// your method
public boolean meetsPreconditions(final LineFeature feature) {
final RoadElementsChain roadElementsChain = createRoadElementsChainBuilder();
roadElementsChain.buildRoadElementsChain(feature);
if(isNotSmallSlipRoad(feature)){
   return false;
}
if (isLineFeaturesEmpty(roadElementsChain)){
    return false;
}
if(isOtherLineFeaturesStartTooShort(roadElementsChain)){
    return false;
}
if(isOtherLineFeaturesEndTooShort(roadElementsChain)) {
    return false;
}
setChainOfRoads(roadElementsChain);
return true;
} // end of your method
```

Finally you can write tests for all of your methods (public and protected as well).
You should also check Mockito for [Mock](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-annotations) and [Spy](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy).